# How to detect file transfer in Lync conversation

Tags: .net, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to log my Lync convrsation using a console application which uses Lync SDK to access Lync client. 
My code looks similar to this:

```
       public void GetNotifiedAboutMessageSent()
    {
        var client = LyncClient.GetClient();

        foreach (var conversation in client.ConversationManager.Conversations)
            foreach (var participant in conversation.Participants)
                ((InstantMessageModality)participant.Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage]).InstantMessageReceived += participant_InstantMessageReceived;
    }

    //Event handlers
    void participant_InstantMessageReceived(object sender, MessageSentEventArgs e)
    {
        LogText("Message received");
    }
```

participant_InstantMessageReceived event is raised when message is sent or received but is not raised when file is sent (or received). Is there an event similar to this on file transfer which I can subscribe to or another way to get notification when file is sent over Lync?

Answer (score 0):

Lync client SDK and UCMA or UCWA do not support file transfer.
There is a way when extending UCMA classes, but without a direct link to the developers of Microsoft, you will probably not achieve it.
Short: It's too far to go.
If possible switch to Teams and hope Microsoft lives up to their goal of implementing it there.